# Concatenate columns of dataframe in array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to make a data visualization app, which is introduced a file type CSV and then select the columns to represent (not all columns are represented), I already got the function to select only a few variables, but now I need to join those columns in a single data frame to work with, I tried to do this:

```
for i  in range(0, len(data1.columns)):
    i = 0
    df = np.array(data1[data1.columns[i]])
    i +=1
    print(df)
```

But I've only got the same column repeated numb_selection = numb_columns_dataframe (i.e. if I select 5 columns, the same column returns 5 times)

How do I ensure that for each iteration I insert a different column and not always the same one?

Comment: You can iterate over the column names using `for col in data1:`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of repeating one column is in `i` rewriting.

```py
# For example `data1.columns` is ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

# Your code:

for i in range(0, len(data1.columns)):
    i = 0  # Here, in every interaction, set into 0
    print(i, data1.columns[i], sep=": ")
    i += 1

# Output:
# 0: a
# 0: a
# 0: a
# 0: a
# 0: a
```

`i = 0` & `i += 1` are useless because you already get `i` from`range`, ranging from 0 to `len (data1.columns)`.

Fixed version

```py
for i in range(0, len(data1.columns)):
   print(i, data1.columns[i], sep=": ")

# Output:
# 0: a
# 1: b
# 2: c
# 3: d
# 5: e
```

Versions using manual increment `i` plus iteration through elements:

```py
# First step, iter over columns
for col in data1.columns:
    print(col)

# Output:
# a
# b
# c
# d
# e

# Step two, manual increment to obtain the list (array) index
i = 0
for col in data1.columns:
    print(i, col, sep=": ")
    i += 1

# Output:
# 0: a
# 1: b
# 2: c
# 3: d
# 5: e
```

***Helpful to know, `enumerate`:***

Function `enumerate(iterable)` is nice for obtain key of index and value itself.

```
print(list(enumerate(["Hello", "world"])))

# Output:
[
  (0, "Hello"),
  (1, "world")
]
```

Usage:

```py
for i, col in enumerate(data1.columns):
    print(i, col, sep=": ")

# Output:
# 0: a
# 1: b
# 2: c
# 3: d
# 5: e
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved it, declaring an empty list before the loop, iterating on the selected variables and saving the indexes in this list. So I get a list with the indexes that I should use for my visualization.

```
def get_index(name):
            '''
            return the index of a column name
            '''
            for column in df.columns:
                if column == name:
                    index = df.columns.get_loc(column)
                    return index

        result=[]
        for i  in range(len(selected)):
            X = get_index(selected[i])
            result.append(X)

        df = df[df.columns[result]]
        x = df.values
```

Where 'selected' is the list of selected variables (filter first by column name, then get its index number), I don't know if it's the most elegant way to do this, but it works well.